# Core Data: Fetch result from multiple entities or relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have two entities. `Employee` entity

```
@interface Employee : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * dept;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Department *deptEmp;

@end
```

and `Department` entity

```
@interface Department : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Employee *deptEmp1;
```

I am trying to fetch information from both with following predicate

```
NSMutableString *queryString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(name = 'Apple') AND (deptEmp1.location like 'Cupertino')"];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

**And Fetch Request is**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType]; // NSFetchRequestResultType - NSDictionaryResultType
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Department",nil]];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];
```

**Setting Predicate**

```
if(![queryString isEqualToString:@""])
{
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:queryString]];
}

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *returnArray = nil;
```

**Fetching Result**

```
@synchronized(self)
{
    returnArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

But here I never get result.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to retrieve? Thanks.

Comment: I want to fetch name,dept from first entity and location from second with Predicate condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if you want to retrieve an `Employee` who works in  a specific department name and in a specific location, I'll use a the following code:

```
NSMutableString *queryString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"deptEmp1.name == %@ AND deptEmp1.location == %@", @"Apple", @"Cupertino"]; 
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Department",nil]];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];

NSArray* returnArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if([returnArray count] > 0) {

   Employee* emp = [returnArray objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", emp.name, emp.dept, emp.deptEmp.location);
}
```

*Few notes*

Why do you use a lock on the request?
Have you set a inverse rel?
Maybe do you need to set up a one-to-many rel between `Department` and `Employee`?

Try and let me know.

**Edit**

Try this one. I didn't notice the query string in your question.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deptEmp1.name == %@ AND deptEmp1.location == %@", @"Apple", @"Cupertino"]; 
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Department",nil]];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];

NSArray* returnArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if([returnArray count] > 0) {

   Employee* emp = [returnArray objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", emp.name, emp.dept, emp.deptEmp.location);
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Department",nil]];

NSArray* returnArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for(Employee* emp in returnArray) {

   NSLog(@"%@", emp);
   NSLog(@"%@", emp.deptEmp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In query string i have changed deptEmp1 to deptEmp and settings as per your Note, It runs without any error. but return nothing, even i have records for same in DB.

Comment: Sorry, dear but this doesn't work. Isn't there any sample code that i can follow?, as i tried since 2-3 days didn't find any solution. I am not sure if issue is in code or model.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I added an edit. Are you able to see the employee you are interested in?

Comment: Your 'Edit 2' gives prefect result. now it seems there is some hope.

Comment: @kamleshwar Print also the department. What do you see? See edit.

Comment: This means you have no department for employees.

Comment: You code is perfect, there was some issue while store data relation was mismatch while storing data. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a reverse relationship.
Your Department object need to look like that:

```
@interface Department : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *deptEmp1;
```

Like that all Departement has a collection of Employee and a Employee work at a one Departement.

And on your predicate you need to adjust "deptEmp1.name" to "deptEmp.name"